# Does the Community Edition of DolphinDB support high availability?

Tags: high-availability, dolphindb, community-server

I'm going to try the Community Edition. I want to know if this edition can support high availability. Since the community edition can only use two data/compute nodes, can I build a high-availability cluster with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DolphinDB HA cluster offers high availability for both metadata and data, which can tolerate the failure of a single node without interrupting operation.

Metadata is stored on controllers. To ensure its high availability, DolphinDB adopts the Raft protocol to form a group with multiple controllers. The cluster can continue to operate as long as more than half of the controllers are available.

DolphinDB supports storing chunk replicas on different nodes. If one or more data nodes fail, the database can still function with at least one available replica. Data consistency across multiple replicas is ensured by a two-phase commit protocol.

DolphinDB APIs support automatic reconnection and switching mechanism for high availability. If a data node becomes unavailable, the API will attempt to reconnect to it. If the attempt fails, the API will automatically switch to another available node.

The Community Edition of DolphinDB allows for deploying two data/compute nodes, which supports high availability for data and API clients. However, it does not support high availability for metadata, which requires at least three nodes.

The Community Edition has the same features as the Enterprise Edition. The only difference is the limitations on CPU cores and memory.